# How to do port mirroring in Juniper EX2200 switch

Tags: juniper, switching, juniper-junos, mirror

I am using Juniper EX2200 switch, one of the connected System generating lot of unwanted traffic ( varying from 10 Mb to 25 Mb upload traffic). I wanted to  analyse those traffic using port mirroring and network tools like wireshark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requirements

- Junos OS Release 9.0 or later for EX Series switches

  One EX Series switch

  set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching

  ```
  set interfaces ge-0/0/1 unit 0 family inet 192.1.1.1/24

  set interfaces ge-0/0/10 unit 0 family ethernet-switching

  set ethernet-switching-options analyzer employee-monitor input ingress interface ge-0/0/0.0

  set ethernet-switching-options analyzer employee-monitor input ingress interface ge-0/0/1.0

  set ethernet-switching-options analyzer employee-monitor output interface ge-0/0/10.0
  ```

> [Refer for more details.](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/example/port-mirroring-local-ex-series.html)